# Make [potato] a synonym of [potatoes]

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

There are two separate tags for potatoes: [potato](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potato) and [potatoes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potatoes), and the questions in them don't seem to be different in any way.

Could someone with enough rep merge the two? (I would recommend keeping the latter and making the first a synonym.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly they mean something different; [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37370/potato-crisp-making) is tagged with both [potato](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potato) and [potatoes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potatoes)!

Or at least it was. Merged, thanks.